# EXISTS and output parameter in stored procedure in mysql

Tags: mysql, stored-procedures, exists

Here is my stored procedure for returning true if any data is found in document details but it generates an error

" #1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '@result = true end if end' at line 5"

```
create procedure abcde(out result boolean)
    begin

        if exists(select * from document_details)
        then @result = true;
        end if
    end
```

Kindly,provide me a solution asap

Comment: @result is a user-define variable, not an output parameter. I suggest that you read [Variables in Stored Programs](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/stored-program-variables.html) in the reference manual.

Comment: then please suggest me what would be the code
how can I retrieve value as output parameter

Answer (score 0):

Besides the fact that you need to use `SET` to assign a value to a local variable or a parameter, there are other things worth mentioning

1. you have to have a semicolon after `END IF`
2. since `EXSITS()` returns `BOOLEAN` you can just directly assign it to your `OUT` parameter

That being said your stored procedure might look like

```
CREATE PROCEDURE abcde(OUT result BOOLEAN)
  SET result = 
  (
    EXISTS(SELECT * 
             FROM document_details)
  );
```

*Note: now it's just one statement. Therefore you don't even need to change `DELIMITER` and use `BEGIN ... END` block.*

Here is **[SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/59c8b/1)** demo